# Mongodb Backup over nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongoDB instance and using via my NodeJs/Express App. I have hosted it on Openshift. I am not able to figure out how to run a cron to backup the db.

I dont want to backup to s3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) package to run your cron.

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

// Runs at 12am daily
schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 12 * *', function(){
    // Perform your database query to update your backup
});
```

**OR** Create a new DB (let's call it backup) and each time you update your actual DB, also insert into the backup DB.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped

Answer (score 0):

try the package node-schedule for a cron like process.